# BizTalk mapping: how to extract single row from looping

Tags: xslt, biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-2013, biztalk-mapper

I have the following issue. In BizTalk core (XML) I have a tag which may be replicated few times. It's cardinality is n, let's say - in theory 0 ≤ n ≤ 99. Let's call it Note[n].

In outgoing file (it's flat) I have five (exactly five) appropriate fields. Let's call them FTX1..5. So what I need to do is to map `Note[1]` (if it exists) to FTX1, `Note[2]` (if it exists) to FTX2, ..., `Note[5]` (if it exists) to FTX5.

Is it possible to do this using only Functoids? I tried to use Looping functoid but I don't understand how to extract every iteration. On the other hand I don't understand if I can use Table looping and Table extractor since actually I don't have a table.

So I need something like you can see at the picture. Actually task is even more complicated but let's start from this.

Does anyone know if this can be solved only by Functoids?

I would appreciate any advice..

[image: Picture of what I need to do]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the Iteration functoid and the Equal functoid.

Link Note to each of the FreeText nodes and also to the Iteration functoid.  Link that to a series of equal functoids with values of ranging from 2 to 5 and link those to the FreeText nodes as well.

[image]

Input file

```
<ns0:Root xmlns:ns0="http://Scratch.SO65382125in">
  <Note>Note_0</Note>
  <Note>Note_1</Note>
  <Note>Note_2</Note>
</ns0:Root>
```

Output (formatted)

```
<ns0:Root xmlns:ns0="http://Scratch.SO65382125out">
    <FreeText1>Note_0</FreeText1>
    <FreeText2>Note_1</FreeText2>
    <FreeText3>Note_2</FreeText3>
</ns0:Root>
```

Note that it works without a Looping Functoid but does show the warning

> The destination node "FreeText2" has multiple inputs. For a destination node to have multiple inputs, one of its ancestors should be connected to a looping functoid.

You can get rid of that warning by adding a Looping Functoid

[image]

Comment: Dijkgraaf, thanks for fast answer and thank you so much for solution. It works. But, as I mentioned, task is even more complicated...so the second part of this task is:

Comment: Dijkgraaf, thanks for fast answer and thank you so much for solution. It works. But as I mentioned, task is even more complicated..so the second part of this task is: each FreeText has a limit 70 characters. But Note in theory has no limits. So, in the most simple case, when length of all Notes is less than 70 chars, we just map Note[1..5] to FTX1..5. But. If Note[1] contains, for example, 200 chars, I chould map first 70 to FTX1, next 70 to FTX2, last 60 to FTX3. Then I should take Note[2], map to FTX4 and Note[3] to FTX5. The rest should be ignored. Can this be done with functoids? Thanks!

Comment: Dijkgraaf, I put second part of a task in a comment since it's related to the first part. Is it better to ask new question? Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelMS It would be better to ask a new question, yes.  Fundamentally changing the question after it has been answered tends to be frowned upon.  You can link back to the original question if it helps to clarify the new question